# How to clear form after successfully submitting Formik form using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, formik

I am currently working on a React project which uses Redux and Redux-saga.
I am wondering how to make the form reset after successfully completing the async api call.
using redux and redux saga am I using the

```
resetform({})
```

but it immediately resets the form before api is successfully executed

Comment: do it in the success block of api

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS api operation is done through redux-saga.which doesn't have access to the view..

Comment: @anilkumar - I think you should use `resetForm()` or use create a ref for handling reset within `componentDidUpdate()` .

Comment: Please share the code of your component so that we can understand your logical flow

Answer (score 0):

What I will do :

- Make the call to the api,
- with Redux, you can update in the store an entry like : `isSubmitted` which is a boolean.
- after this, just check the props isSubmitted and when it's `true` just call the resetForm();
- You can check the props with an effect (useEffect) or if you use an older version of react, componentDidUpdate.

According to the doc of [Formik](https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-formik-sagas-issues-3pq62) :

```
The latter is useful for calling resetForm within componentDidUpdate or useEffect.
```

Hope it helps.